# On what PORT is my docker container with a React app running? Reacts' default PORT or EXPOSE from Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, mapping, port

I'm a newbie to Docker so please correct me if anything I'm stating is wrong.

I created a React app and wrote a following Dockerfile in the root repository:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:latest

# A directory within the virtualized Docker environment
# Becomes more relevant when using Docker Compose later
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
# Copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package*.json ./
 
# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install
 
# Copies everything over to Docker environment
COPY . .
 
# Uses port which is used by the actual application
EXPOSE 8080
 
# Finally runs the application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

My goal is to run the docker image in a way, that I can open the React app in my browser (with localhost).
Since in the Dockerfile I'm Exposing the app to the PORT: 8080. I thought I can run:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t <name of the docker image>
```

But apparently the application is accessible through 3000 in the container, cause when I run:

```
docker run -p 8080:3000 -t <name of the docker image>
```

I can access it with localhost:8080.

What's the point of the EXPOSE port in the Dockerfile, when the service running in its container is accessible through a different port?
When containerizing a NodeJS app, do I always have to make sure that process.env.PORT in my app is the same as the EXPOSE in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EXPOSE` is for telling docker what ports from inside the application **can** be exposed. It doesn't mean anything if you do not use those port inside (container -> host).

The `EXPOSE` is very handy when using `docker run -P -t <name of the docker image>` (`-P` capital P) to let Docker automatically publish all the exposed ports to random ports on the host (try it out. then run `docker ps` or `docker inspect <containerId>` and checking the output).

So if your web Server (React app) is running on port 3000 (inside the container) you should `EXPOSE 3000` (instead of 8080) to properly integrate with the Docker API.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of weird.
Its just documentation in a sense.

[https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#:~:text=The%20EXPOSE%20instruction%20informs%20Docker,not%20actually%20publish%20the%20port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#:%7E:text=The%20EXPOSE%20instruction%20informs%20Docker,not%20actually%20publish%20the%20port).

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
> functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
> image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
> intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
> the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
> more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
> to high-order ports.

> do I always have to make sure that process.env.PORT in my app is the
> same as the EXPOSE in the Dockerfile?
> Yes. You should.

And then you also need to make sure that port actually gets published, when you use the docker run command or in your docker-compose.yml file, or however you plan on running docker.

Answer (score 1):

Actually react app runs the default port 3000. so you must to mention ports and expose in `docker-compose.yml`. Now I'm changing the 3000 port to 8081

```
  frontend: 
      container_name: frontend 
      build: 
        context: ./frontend/app
        dockerfile: ../Dockerfile  
      volumes:
        - ./frontend/app:/home/devops/frontend/app 
        - /home/devops/frontend/app/node_modules
      ports:
        - "8081:3000"
      expose:
        - 8081
      command: ["npm", "start"]
      restart: always 
      stdin_open: true
```

And run the docker

```
$ sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Then check the running containers for find the running port

```
$ sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
83b970baf16d        devops_frontend     "docker-entrypoint..."   31 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds       8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->3000/tcp   frontend
```

It's resolved. check your public port

```
$ curl 'http://0.0.0.0:8081'
```